# Battery Protection IC: How to ensure that even under-voltage batteries are allowed to be charged?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, low-power, lipo

As I understand, the battery protection circuit isolates the battery from the battery connector if it detects undervoltage condition.

If this happens, how can the system ever charge the battery and make it usable?
I know that, the battery voltage would recover after sometime and it can be charged at that time, however,if the device is not plugged into a charger for a long time, then after several cycles of turning off and on, eventually, the battery would contain so little charge that it's voltage won't rise enough for the battery protection IC to enable it. So the battery would remain isolated behind the battery protection circuit and the system won't ever be able to charge it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would largely depend on the chip you're talking about (next time, maybe links?)

But most implement a back-to-back MOSFET, either internally or externally, where UVLO (under voltage lock-out) disables one MOSFET and OVLO (over voltage lock-out) disables the other, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOzc6u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As displayed in the image; D1 is the internal Body Diode of the MOSFET M1, and so D2 is inside M2. They are a given.

---

If the chip sees 2.5V or lower on Vbat it will turn off M1, this will block current going out, but the body diode will always allow current in, as long as M2 is turned on.

If the chip sees 4.25V or more on Vbat it will turn off M2, whit will block current going in, but the body diode will always allow current out, as long as M1 is turned on.

Of course the chip would prefer to always have both MOSFETs on, if the situation allows, because they usually have lower voltage drop at operational current than the diodes, but even if it takes a few seconds to turn a MOSFET back on, the bode diode will always allow current to flow in the other direction.

Many chips also have a Vout line to sense the voltage drop across the MOSFETs, allowing it to turn off for a few ms to a few seconds when it is higher than a given voltage. This allows an engineer to select two MOSFETs with an On Resistance such that a specific current limit is set.

For example if both MOSFETs have 50 mOhm on Resistance at the working voltage and the chip senses a limit of 100mV. The two MOSFETs together will have 100 mOhm, 100 mV over 100 mOhm will yield a current limit of 1A.

Comment: I have not specified the battery protection IC numbers as I would be using off the shelf batteries with built in protection. I believe  there is some unwritten convention for the expected parameters. And because of this one does not have to worry about the protection circuit parameters unless the application wants to operate very close to the various threshold values. I wanted to know the recharge-after-deep-discharge strategy for such general purpose applications. I have one battery which shows 0 volts, and refuses to charge. I was expecting it to atleast take a slow charge ...(contd..)

Comment: .. and your answer underlines the same expectation. So now I'll have to examine its battery protection circuit and find whether this behaviour is by design or some component is faulty.

Comment: @Dojo if you charge with a few mA and it doesn't jump up to 2.5V or more your battery is dead. Period. A battery that's unattended after low charge state for half a year or so will do that. Lithium chemistry needs care just as any other.